# How to show view for a unique row from custom database table on Drupal 8?

Tags: views, theming, database

I'm using drupal 8, and I have a custom table that was created with schema from my module on install file.

```
$schema['md_noticias'] = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'id'=>array(
                'type'=>'serial',
                'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'id_plone'=>array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'mysql_type' => 'BIGINT',
                'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'titulo'=>array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'mysql_type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 350,
                'not null' => TRUE,
        ),      
        'descripcion'=>array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'mysql_type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 1000,
                'not null' => TRUE,
        ),          
        'cuerpo'=>array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'mysql_type' => 'text',
                'not null' => TRUE,
        ),  
        'titulo_imagen'=>array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'mysql_type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 500,
                'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'fecha_creacion'=>array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'length' => 11,
                'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'creador'=>array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'mysql_type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 250,
                'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'imagen'=>array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'mysql_type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 600,
                'not null' => TRUE,
        )
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
);
```

I show a table with all rows thats have a delete action. But.

How can I create a display view for a unique row with format for public users. For example:

```
<h1>$myrow["titulo"]</h1>
<p class="description">$myrow["descripcion"]</p>
<p class="body">$myrow["cuerpo"]</p>
<img src='$myrow["imagen"]' title='$myrow["titulo"]' />
```

Thanks!